# How to retrieve files created by an android app?

Tags: android

My android app creates an sqlite database and I need to get it off the device so I can look at the data with a database viewer.

Was hoping I could just issue >adb shell and then go find it somewhere on the file system. Looks like there are permission issues with lots of commands. Even just running >find . -name *.sqlite gives permission denied.

Can anyone advise on how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your device is not rooted, anyway..

Copy your .db file form `/data/data/<package_name>/databases/` to `ExternalStorage` using code.. Then you can get it via `adb pull` command or `DDMS -> FIle Explorer`.

Comment: Also try with `cat source_file > dest_file` command and copy file at External directory using adb shell. Now you can get it via adb pull.. (I didn't test it)

Comment: Nice idea but I can't get at the source file without being root. Guess I need to find out how to be root on the device.

Comment: This is the correct answer ... more detail on how to do it can be found here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166920/android-database-export-works-on-emulator-not-on-phone

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to browse database on the device (without getting the root permission as you want) .

You can browse your database from emulator using adb shell.